# Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532) Typescript y Mongodb

Tags: typescript, mongodb

Tengo la siguiente funcion

```
export const getPackOptions = async  (res: Response) => {
    const d = await connect();
    const result = await d.collection('task').find({}).toArray();
    res.json(result);
};
```

y me subraya la **d** dice

> const d: Db | undefined
> Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

Yo estoy usando "typescript": "^4.2.2"
"mongodb": "^3.6.4",
Y sus respectivos @types instalados.

la funcion con la cual me conecto

```
export async function connect() {
    try {
        const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser: true});
        const db = client.db('packs');
        return db;
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Te remarca ese "error" ya que como tienes escrita actualmente tu función `connect()` verás que el retorno es de tipo `Promise<Db | undefined>`. Esto se debe a que en el bloque `catch` no estás retornando nada si ocurre un error (de ahí viene el undefined), y de hecho ahí también deberías obtener algo como:

> Not all code paths return a value.(7030)

Por lo que lo ideal sería que relanzaras el error o en su defecto lanzar un nuevo error.

Tu código sería así:

```js
export async function connect() {
    try {
        const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser: true});
        const db = client.db('packs');
        return db;
    } catch(e) {
        // console.log(e);
        throw new Error('Algo salió mal'); // Puede ser un nuevo error
        throw new e; // O el mismo error
    }
};

export const getPackOptions = async (res: Response) => {
    const d = await connect();
    const result = await d.collection('task').find({}).toArray();
    res.json(result);
};
```

Por mínimo y/o tonto que parezca, con eso estás indicando que el retorno de dicha función será de tipo `Promise<Db>` y por lo tanto no deberías obtener ni un problema.

Comment: hola, [object Object],[object Object], tengo dos campos en la bd y me los trae asi como object Object, que puede ser el error?

Comment: Eso te muestra con `console.log`, deberías usar [`console.dir`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Console/dir). Saludos

Comment: No es un error, como menciona Mauricio puedes utilizar `console.dir` ya que el nivel de profundidad que te muestra `console.log` depende de la cantidad de propiedades y niveles que tenga el objeto en cuestión.

Comment: probe con console.dir pero me devuelve el object Object pintado de color de verde en la consola, no me da las propiedades del objeto

Comment: Prueba a imprimir solo la propiedad que quieres. Por ejemplo, si lo que te aparece así es la propiedad `cuatro` que se encuentra a cuatro niveles de profundidad desde la raíz, usarías `console.log(objeto.uno.dos.tres.cuatro);`. Si obtienes lo que esperas ver, entonces te tocará a ti tratar con la información, ya sea enviándola a otra aplicación, al cliente, etc.